# Design ideas about application level context cache (similar to session/application context in a web)

Tags: java, caching

We have an web application which involves **creating some heavy Utility Objects** (in terms of memory performance). Its **usage can be on any application tier**. These utility objects are specific to user. So ideally what should have been happening is create these objects when the user logs in, cache them 'somewhere' and reuse them wherever needed.

The **available options** right now are Session,Application. But these are not available to all the tiers. One way is to pass these to subsequent tiers. But this will **violate the Separation of Concerns** approach and other tier will need to know about web tier.

Another approach is t use a **static utility class** to cache these objects. Something like

```
MyUtilObject myObject = MyUtilCache.getMyUtilObject(userName);
```

Internally, backed up by something like a HashMap (and possibly a soft reference). These objects would be cleaned on user logout or session expiry.

Here is what we are using

JBoss, Struts1.2, Spring. All the tiers on on the same machine (in single runtime).

Please share your thoughts/approaches on this.

Comment: You could use a LinkedHashMap as an LRU cache to prevent it getting too large.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Yes I was considering that. Thanks for the suggestion. BTW forty questions ? total questions I asked is 17 !

Comment: My mistake, You have 156 *Answers*

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html#removeEldestEntry%28java.util.Map.Entry%29 for any one else interested.

Answer (score 1):

All you need is an interface that is common to all tiers. The implementation can be backed by the `Session` and injected wherever it is required.

Answer (score 0):

> creating some heavy Utility Objects

Explain in details when user logs in , what kind of  heavy objects are stored over a period of time?

It is always good to have smaller datain HttpSession.Typical web application session lasts for seconds or minutes for an user. Mostly it should contain authorization, user preferences, connection infos and  states .it should not contain data , that is useful from current page to next. Of course you can store too much data , for session heap is the limit. But there could be race condition if you store for long time. If the data is required for this request, then keep in HttpRequest. Otherwise you have 2nd level caches such as **EHCACHE**,**MEMCACHE** or **TerraCotta**,apply policies such as till the session  expires , make this cache available for all the pages. Also between each pages pass a unique id , that determines cache info.

> Another approach is t use a static utility class to cache these
>   objects

Static class is common to all users. How can you have static class specific to user.

Comment: not sure why you need "details" of heavy object. Any object which takes lot of resources during its life cycle is heavy. By Static class I mean the container class and not the actual user specific data.

Comment: I was asking about  what kind of information you store like ,encrypted username, also what is the size of object you store.

Comment: To give an example/analogy, lets say something like a database connection object, this cannot be shared. I create it once, it remains valid till the user session and closed on logout/session expiry.

Comment: database connection object in session ? , what if connection becomes stale , user cannot do anything. what if suddenly u try to run something parallel , everything will fall apart.

Comment: @Santhosh: are you working on internal web app, or public usage web app.

Answer (score 0):

Why not Serialize/De-serialize the objects as and when required. When the Objects are required at that point De-serialize them and at session close serialize them again

Comment: Serialization is not an option as the type of objects I am dealing with cannot be serialized.